# What is the benefit of front-end framework wrappers for charting libraries (i.e. vue-chartjs, react-chartjs-2...etc.)?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, frameworks, chart.js, chartist.js

What is the benefit of using a front-end framework wrapper for Javascript charting libraries?

The only benefit I have come across thus far is that you can import only the charts you need (i.e. import { Bar }...), whereas using a CDN imports all the charting library code whether you use it or not.

However, by using a wrapper you are adding another layer to your code that may not be maintained long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically these will bind the data used to create the chart with your front-end framework. If your framework is made of Components, it is "simple" to create a new chart with data already in your component's scope. Especially if you have charts all over your app, putting them into a component will save a lot of cut-n-paste code.

Or if your chart changes data, most frameworks will "watch" for when a data value/property has been updated and have a hook to re-create the chart. The data binding is part of the framework and utilized by the wrapper so you do not have to.

If you're using a framework, the wrapper will make using the chart seem more "natural" to the other parts on the page. Plus, if the wrapper project is actually maintained/updated, you can get some new features and bug fixes without much trouble.

Overall it's likely just a time-saving thing. One can always write their own code, and maintain their own code. I'm sure there are cases where manually updating the chart is useful, but for simple implementations the wrapper is often faster.

Comment: I think out of all the benefits you've mentioned the automatic update is likely the most useful.

I find that it's only time saving if you're recreating the same chart type time and time again.

If you're only implementing a couple of charts, oftentimes the time it takes to learn how the wrapper works and to update it when new versions come mean that it's a wash time-wise.

Thanks :)